# Making Decisions using Random

Tags: c#, if-statement, random, generator

I am trying to create a random choice maker. I want my program to pick a random number then apply it to an if. Like this -

```
Random random = new Random();
random.next(0, 10).ToString());
if (random == 1)
{
messagebox.show("Good Joke")
}
else if(random == 2)
{
messagebox.show("Terrible Joke")
}
```

etc...

Could someone help please.

Comment: First of all use a static field for the random instance. Secondly you can use a switch statement where each case represents the result. Tbh it's not too clear what your issue is.

Comment: What I wanted to do was pick a random number. Then based on the random number I wanted the if/else statement to show a certain message box.

Comment: Always avoid static fields.

Comment: @HenkHolterman could you tell us why? Static fields are not always bad.

Answer (score 1):

This is just initilizing `Random`, and Invoking `Next` method with a range of numbers.

**Original code issues:**

1. You're using `next` and not `Next`, `C#` is Case-Sensitive.
2. You're not storing the results of the `Next` operation.
3. The `ToString` is redundant, no need to cast to `string`.

**Code:**

```
var random = new Random();
int number = random.Next(0, 10);

// If you gonna use alot of conditions like this, a better solution will be to use: switch
if (number == 1)
{
    // Do Something
}
else if (number == 2)
{
    // Do Something else
}
```

[.NET Fiddle Link](https://dotnetfiddle.net/l9ShH3)

Comment: Thanks. It works fine and much easier than some of the other methods i've seen on other websites.

Comment: @Sachin, Bauss have gave you a good examples, especially the 2nd with the `Dictionary`, If your starting to get confused use mine, otherwise I would suggest you, using Bauss 2nd example. Anyhow feel free to UpVote\Accept the answers that helped you.

Answer (score 1):

There is a few ways this can be done. Here are three of them.

First way is to create an array of the messages.

```
string[] messages = new string[]
{
    "Good Joke",
    "Terrible Joke"
};
// ...
MessageBox.Show(messages[random.Next(messages.Length)]);
```

The second way to do it would be with a dictionary, that way you can add / remove entries easily during runtime. Make sure the keys matches indexes though.

```
Dictionary<int,string> messages = new Dictionary<int,string>()
{
    { 0, "Good Joke" }
    { 1, "Terrible Joke" }
};
// ...
MessageBox.Show(messages[random.Next(messages.Count)]);
```

At last you could use a switch statement.

```
string msg = string.Empty;
switch (random.Next(2)) // The amount of cases ...
{
    case 0: msg = "Good Joke"; break;
    case 1: msg = "Terrible Joke"; break;
}
MessageBox.Show(msg);
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got to store the output of random.Next in a variable like this.

```
Random random = new Random();
var val = random.Next(0, 10);
if (val == 1)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Good Joke");
}
else if(val == 2)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Terrible Joke");
}
```